# Update All instance of DispositionAuthority SharePoint Group in Site Collection

Tags: 2013, groups

We have a main site collection with 300+ sub-sites, and need to figure out how to loop through all instances of the 'DispositionAuthority' SharePoint group and add users to this SharePoint Group, so they will be notified of records set to expire due to content type retention policies.

I've been searching for a PowerShell script, but haven't found anything.

Comment: What is the actual problem, adding users to a group or somehow setting up notifications?

Comment: The problem is we need to add an AD Group to these 'DispositionAuthority' SharePoint Groups.  This will be much more manageable as people move departments and even leave the company, that way we just need to update the AD Group and it cascades to all these DispositionAuthority SharePoint groups and we are still helping + managing expiring documents.

Comment: We'd like to update these 'DispositionAuthority' SharePoint Groups via a script rather than having to do it manually just because of the size of our site collection.

Comment: This may do it...will have to test:$site=get-spsite http://sitecollection
#get web object
$web=$site.RootWeb

#Enumarate site groups
$web.SiteGroups |select name
#get user object
$user=$web.EnsureUser("domain\myUser")
#Get group object
$group=$web.SiteGroups["DispositionAuthority"]
#add user to group
$group.AddUser($user)